# Swift: Declaring empty tuples

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

What's the correct way to declare an empty tuple?

- For Arrays: `var myArr : [String] = []`
- For tuples: `var myTuple: (key: String, val: Int) = ()` ?

Is there a correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Adding the values or making it optional

Comment: you can initialize it with "" and 0

Comment: @LeoDabus "magic values" like `""` and `0` can be dangerous if those values are valid.

Comment: @JackLawrence in that case he can declare key: String?,  val: Int?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's no such thing as an "unfilled" tuple value. In other words you don't create an empty tuple and then add values to it later. It's important to remember that tuples aren't collections like `Array` or `Dictionary`. Tuples are structured types. For example, you can't iterate through a tuple with a for loop. In your example, `myTuple` is a single value that happens to contain a `String` and an `Int`.

A tuple is like an on-demand unnamed structure, such as the following struct but if it were possible for it to be unnamed:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let key: String
    let val: Int
}
```

If you want to model a missing tuple value, you should make the type of the entire tuple optional. For example:

```
var myTuple: (key: String, val: Int)? = nil
```

Comment: Note that there is an *empty tuple* - it is the return type of functions that return nothing i.e. `Void`. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/void

Comment: I dunno; "There's no such thing as an empty/unfilled tuple value" is ambiguous. Although it is true that one can't add elements to an empty tuple in the way that one can add elements to an empty array, empty tuples certainly do exist. The answer would be better if that distinction were made clear.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit to make that clear. I was trying to relate to the vocabulary the question was using, but in this case that definitely leads to an inaccuracy.